# WPF, Datagrid with restricted input

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls, datagridtemplatecolumn

recently I have started a new project in c#- Fireworks planning software. I am quite experienced in WinForms, but I want to learn WPF. So I have passed a couple of tutorials, but still on very beginning.

The task is to make a datagrid, where user puts data for each Firing point, thus for instance
Cue, EffectTime, DelayBeforeEffect, FiringTime and Name (it is not complete). [Main window preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYj6X.png)

No the thing is the time (EffectTime etc.) has to be input by user via keyboard and I want to:

1. if the value is like sss.fff (simple number or decimal number)
   the program converts it automatically to TimeSpan (h:mm:ss.fff),
   which is actually resolution of My firing system. Example: number
   65.528 is converted to 0:01:05.528.
2. negative values are also allowed, because there are several
   things have to be done before main pyrotechnics show starts
3. I would like validate user input it is valid time value, not for
   instance 65.528.20. If the value is not correct I need either cancel
   user leave the editedcell or at least rewrite the new value with
   last validated
4. there is some relationship between values, for instance: FiringPoint
   = EffectTime - Delay, or better `FiringPoint = EffectTime.Subtract(Delay);`

As I am used to I have created a `UserControl TimeText` with only one element - `TextBox` and I check, eventually correct,  input upon points listed above. 
Then I have created `DataGrid` and `DataGridTemplateColumn` in MainWindow, 
classes like

- `FiringPoint` (with properties listeda above),
- `FiringPointManager` with `ObservableCollection<FiringPoint>` implementing `INotifyChange` interface
- Data Binding between Manager and DataGrid.

  After facing VisualStudio for about 20 hours, it is really working, but it seems to be very complicated. 
  Because for instance I need to forward DataGridRow.Background color to my TimeText control via dependencyProperty etc.

**So finally my question**: Is my approach correct or can somebody suggest better approach how to reach the same functionality?

Thanks for your opinions
Jan

Code for TimeTextBox

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DataGridHratky
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interakční logika pro TimeTextBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TimeTextBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Overrides
        #endregion   
        #region Enum
        #endregion
        #region constants
        private const string __NEG = "-";
        private static readonly string[] __SEP = { ".", "," };
        public const string __TFORMAT = @"%h\:mm\:ss\.fff";
        private const string __COL = ":";
        #endregion
        #region private declarations
        private bool _isNegative = false;
        private double _onlySecondsValue = 0;
        private Brush _okBackground;
        private Brush _nokBackground = Brushes.OrangeRed;
        private Brush _negBackground = Brushes.LavenderBlush;
        private TimeSpan _tsValue = new TimeSpan();
        private bool _bOnlySeconds = false;
        private string _originalValue;
        #endregion
        #region private methods
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if value is only in second format. May be also negative and decimal either with "." or ","
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">text to check</param>
        /// <param name="seconds">Out variable, where seconds should be stored</param>
        /// <returns>true if so</returns>
        private bool onlySeconds(string text, out double seconds)
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator == __SEP[0])
                text = text.Replace(__SEP[1], __SEP[0]);
            else text = text.Replace(__SEP[0], __SEP[1]);
            if (Double.TryParse(text, out seconds))
            {
                _bOnlySeconds = true;
                return true;

            } else
            {
                _bOnlySeconds = false;
                return false;
            }


        }

        private bool validate(string time)
        {
            string _rawValue = time;

            if (onlySeconds(_rawValue, out _onlySecondsValue))
            {

                return true;
            }

            //check if it is negative
            if (_rawValue.StartsWith(__NEG))
            {

                _isNegative = true;

            }
            else _isNegative = false;


            if (TimeSpan.TryParse(_rawValue, out _tsValue)) return true;
            else return false;

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines time based on:
        /// - if there is only one : in string means minutes and seconds
        /// - if there are two : means hours and minutes and seconds
        ///  - in both cases milliseconds after . or , may be present
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sTime">String representing validated time</param>
        /// <returns>Time span with translated time</returns>
        private TimeSpan determineTime(string sTime)
        {
            int _iColon = Regex.Matches(sTime,__COL).Count;
            string _sResult;
            TimeSpan _tsDays = new TimeSpan();

            if (TimeSpan.TryParse(sTime, out _tsDays))
            {
                if (_tsDays.Days > 0)
                    return new TimeSpan(0, _tsDays.Hours, _tsDays.Minutes, _tsDays.Seconds, _tsDays.Milliseconds);
            }



                TimeSpan _ts = new TimeSpan();
                if (_iColon == 1) //minutes and seconds
                {
                    //add 0 hours and 0 days
                    _sResult = addTimeToTimeSpan(sTime, "0.0:");
                }
                else if
                  (_iColon == 2) //hours minutes and seconds
                {

                    //add 0 days
                    _sResult = addTimeToTimeSpan(sTime, "0.");
                }
                else _sResult = sTime;

            if (TimeSpan.TryParse(_sResult, out _ts))
            {
                // in all cases remove day 
                return new TimeSpan(0, _ts.Hours, _ts.Minutes, _ts.Seconds, _ts.Milliseconds);
            }
            else return _ts;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns time with added value, moves __NEG sign if present to the from
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sTime">Original time</param>
        /// <param name="sTimeToAdd">Time to add</param>
        /// <returns>string with complete time</returns>
        private string addTimeToTimeSpan(string sTime, string sTimeToAdd)
        {
            string _sResult;
            if (sTime.StartsWith(__NEG))
            {
                _sResult = __NEG + sTimeToAdd + sTime.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            else _sResult = sTimeToAdd + sTime;
            return _sResult;
        }
        #endregion
        #region Public events
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion
        #region delegates
        #endregion
        #region Public delcarations
        #region Dependency



        public Brush BKColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(BKColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BKColorProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BKColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BKColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BKColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(TimeTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));



        public bool ReadOnly
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ReadOnlyProperty); }
            set { 
                    SetValue(ReadOnlyProperty, value);
                    timeTextBox.ReadOnly = value;
                }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ReadOnly.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ReadOnlyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ReadOnly", typeof(bool), typeof(TimeTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));





        public string TimeText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TimeTextProperty); }
            set {
                SetValue(TimeTextProperty, value);
                    //OnPropertyChanged("TimeText"); 
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeTextProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("TimeText", typeof(string), typeof(TimeTextBox),
                new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnTextPropertyChanged));

        private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
               DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeTextBox myUserControl = dependencyObject as TimeTextBox;
            myUserControl.OnPropertyChanged("TimeText");
            myUserControl.OnTextPropertyChanged(e);
        }
        private void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtTime.Text = TimeText;
        }



        public string Time
        {
            get { return txtTime.Text; }
            set { txtTime.Text = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// True if time span is negative
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsNegative
        {
            get
            {
                return _isNegative;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets validated value background color
        /// </summary>
        public Brush ValueOKBackground
        {
            get
            {
                return _okBackground;
            }
            set
            {
                _okBackground = value;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets background color if value is not succesfully validated
        /// </summary>
        public Brush ValueNotOKBackground
        {
            get
            {
                return _okBackground;
            }
            set
            {
                _nokBackground = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion
        #region Public methods
        #endregion
        #region Constructors

        public TimeTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _okBackground = txtTime.Background;
        }
        #endregion

        private void txtTime_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (validate(txtTime.Text)) txtTime.Background = BKColor;
            else
                txtTime.Background = _nokBackground;
        }

        private void txtTime_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //leave if nothing changed
            if (txtTime.Text == _originalValue) return;

            if (validate(txtTime.Text))
            {
                if (_bOnlySeconds)
                {
                    int seconds = (int)Math.Truncate(_onlySecondsValue);
                    int milliseconds = (int)((_onlySecondsValue - seconds) * 1000);

                    _tsValue = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, seconds, milliseconds);
                }
                else
                {
                    _tsValue = determineTime(txtTime.Text);
                }


            }
            else
            {
                if (!validate(_originalValue)) //validate methods uses _tsValue to put validated timespan
                { 
                _tsValue = new TimeSpan();

                }
            }
            string _sign = _isNegative ? "-" : "";
            txtTime.Text = _sign + _tsValue.ToString(__TFORMAT);
            txtTime.Background = _isNegative ? _negBackground : BKColor;
            TimeText = txtTime.Text;
            txtTime.Background = BKColor;
            OnPropertyChanged("UpdateTime");
        }


        private void txtTime_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _originalValue = txtTime.Text;
            if (!(validate(txtTime.Text))) txtTime.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

TimeText XAML

```
<UserControl x:Name="timeTextBox" x:Class="DataGridHratky.TimeTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridHratky"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <!-- DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:TimeTextBox}}-->  
    <Grid x:Name="grdLayout">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtTime" TextChanged="txtTime_TextChanged" LostFocus="txtTime_LostFocus"  GotFocus="txtTime_GotFocus" BorderThickness="0"
                 Text="{Binding Path=TimeText, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:TimeTextBox}}}"
                 IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=ReadOnly, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:TimeTextBox}}}" 
                 Background="{Binding Path=BKColor, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:TimeTextBox}}}"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>  
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Main Window XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridHratky.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridHratky"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgData"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" AddingNewItem="dgData_AddingNewItem" BeginningEdit="dgData_BeginningEdit" CellEditEnding="dgData_CellEditEnding" RowHeight="25" AlternationCount="2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" >
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Selectable}" Value="False">
                            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                            </DataTrigger.Setters>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="colCue" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedCue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding AvaiableCues}" Width="50" Header="Cue"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colCaption" Width="200" Header="Popis" Binding="{Binding Caption}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Čas efektu"  >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:TimeTextBox  x:Name="ttbFireEffect" TimeText="{Binding Effect, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                BKColor="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="colType" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding AvaiableFWTypes}" Header="Typ" Width="75" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Prodleni">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:TimeTextBox x:Name="ttbDelay" TimeText="{Binding Delay, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                               ReadOnly = "{Binding IsDelayReadOnly}"
                                               BKColor="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Čas odpalu" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:TimeTextBox x:Name="ttbFirePoint" TimeText="{Binding FiringPoint, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                BKColor="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

FirepointManager Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataGridHratky
{
    public class FirepointsManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Enum
        #endregion
        #region constants
        #endregion
        #region private declarations
        private List<string> _avaiableFirepoints = new List<string>();
        private List<string> _avaiableFireworks = new List<string>();
        #endregion
        #region private methods

        #endregion
        #region Public events
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion
        #region Protected
        protected void RaiseChange(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));

        }
        #endregion
        #region delegates
        #endregion
        #region Public properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Firepoints Observable collection
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<FirePoint> FirePoints { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// List of avaiable firepoints
        /// </summary>
        public List<string>AvaiableCues
        {
            get
            {
                return _avaiableFirepoints;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// List of pyrotechnics types
        /// </summary>
        public List<string>AvaiableFWTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return _avaiableFireworks;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Public methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a new Firepoint
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="f">Firepoint</param>
        public void AddFirePoint(FirePoint f)
        {
            f.SelectedCueChanged += F_SelectedCueChanged;
            FirePoints.Add(f);

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks avaible cues and eliminates __MS if already used
        /// </summary>
        public void CheckSelectedCues()
        {
            foreach (var FirePoint in FirePoints)
            {
                if (FirePoint.SelectedCue == FirePoint.__MS)
                {
                    if (_avaiableFirepoints.Contains(FirePoint.__MS))
                        _avaiableFirepoints.Remove(FirePoint.__MS);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (!_avaiableFirepoints.Contains(FirePoint.__MS))
                _avaiableFirepoints.Add(FirePoint.__MS);
            RaiseChange("CuesAvaiable");
        }
        private void F_SelectedCueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckSelectedCues();
        }
        #endregion
        #region Constructors
        public FirepointsManager()
        {
            FirePoints = new ObservableCollection<FirePoint>();
            FirePoints.CollectionChanged += FirePoints_CollectionChanged;
            _avaiableFirepoints = FirePoint.GeneratedCues();
            _avaiableFireworks = FirePoint.FireworksTypes();

        }

        private void FirePoints_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckSelectedCues();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted some code.  The normal approach for what you are doing is to use a DataGridTextColumn with a converter and a set of validation rules in the binding.  Then use a style setter to indicate when an entry is in error.  That said, the way you are approaching it is not wrong.  Everything depends on where you are going from here.  Indeed WPF seems more complex than WinForms because it is capable of so much more.  Suggest simplifying your code and posting it and you will get alternate approaches...there are many.

Comment: So did I. Sorry for the mess in source code as I am learning. But for example question - when selecting entire row, the usercontrol background remains white, whereas standard controls are blue. Should I somehow pass to my UC if it is being selected and selection bk color?

Comment: My top tip is to almost never allow a user to edit directly in a datagrid. Make them pick a row and then edit in a separate control overlaid. You validate separately in that control and they must commit valid data or cancel. If the data is quite simple then use a behaviour to force only valid data input. Which is how the two datagrids in this work https://i.imgur.com/d7iucI8.png

Comment: Not a bad idea, at least for this evening practicing. Using advantages of WPF, I can made a "floating window" over the edited row, so the entire table is still convenient for the user.